# How to find which year do values tend to increase in ? in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Basically I have a table like this:

Table Time:

```
ID.......Date

1......08/26/2016
1......08/26/2016
2......05/29/2016
3......06/22/2016
4......08/26/2015
5......05/23/2015
5......05/23/2015
6......08/26/2014
7......04/26/2014
8......08/26/2013
9......03/26/2013
```

The query should return like this

```
Year........CountNum

2016........4
2015........3
```

To find out which year does its value tend to increase in. I notice that I want to display the years that have more values (number of row in this case) than the previous year.

What I've done so far

```
SELECT Year, count(*) as CountNum 
FROM Time
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY CountNum DESC;
```

I don't know how to get the year from date format. I tried `year(Date)` function, but I got Null data. 
Please help!

Comment: What is the datatype of date column ?

Comment: `mysql` or `sql server`?

Comment: Also `YEAR` function never returns `NULL` unless the input is `NULL` so something else is wrong

Comment: so the year is a virtual column?

Comment: the datatype of date column I used is VARCHAR. I can't use DATE type because when i import with DATE type, the data is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should works fine.

```
select year(date), count(*) as countNum
from time
group by year(date)
order by countNum
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I accepted it. I still work on how to import mm/dd/yyyy values into database with date type. That is the reason I got Null data when I use year(date) function.

Comment: Are you coding in C#? Wich variables are you using for this dates? strings?

Comment: im not coding in C#. I got that part using STR_TO_DATE('column', %c/%e/%Y).

Answer (score 1):

Join the grouped data to itself with 1 year offset:

```
select
a.*
from
(
select year(`Date`) as _year, count(*) as _n 
from time group by 1
) a
left join
(
select year(`Date`) as _year, count(*) as _n 
from time group by 1
) b
on a._year = b._year-1
where a._n > b._n
order by 1
```

Comment: This is also useful :)